# Yosemite: how to save PDF cropped by Preview

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I use Preview to crop a PDF file but it says that the content outside the selection will not be deleted, i.e. they are just hidden, and when printing there do appear.

How to save the cropped PDF?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that it's not straightforwardly possible, unless you delete all other pages (which can be done quickly with the miniature view) and then saving. You can then revert everything back. You could also crop the one page, and then print it to pdf with <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>. Just select `PDF` > `Save as Pdf` and select only the one page you cropped.